# Ext Js IE error only

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, extjs, extjs3

My web app works fine on Firefox or Chrome but not in IE. It shows me the following message:

> Object doesn't support this property or method
>
> File: ext-all.js - Line: 7 - Char: 6100

Any ideas how to fix it?

**BTW: I'm using ext 3.4.**

Edit: All my ext layout creator code:

```
Ext.onReady(function() { 
var viewport = new Ext.Viewport({ 
    layout: 'border', 
    renderTo: document.body, 
    items: [{ 
        region: 'north', 
        height: 25, 
        xtype: 'toolbar', 
        items: [{ 
            xtype: 'button', 
            text: 'Início', 
            iconCls: 'home', 
            handler:function() { 
                var tabs = Ext.getCmp('dynamic-tabs'); 
                tabs.add({ 
                    title: 'Início', 
                    closable:true, 
                    iconCls:'home' 
                }).show(); 
            } 
        }, { 
            xtype: 'button', 
            text: 'Sistema', 
            iconCls: 'sistema',
             menu: {
                 items: [{
                     text: 'Usuários', 
                     iconCls: 'usuario', 
                     handler: function(){ }, 
                     menu: { 
                        items: [{ 
                            text: 'Teste1',
                            iconCls: 'usuario', 
                            handler: function(){ 
                                var tabs = Ext.getCmp('dynamic-tabs'); 
                                tabs.add({ 
                                    title: 'Teste1', 
                                    closable:true, 
                                    autoLoad: 'iframe.php?url=index.php', 
                                    iconCls: 'usuario' 
                                }).show(); 
                            }
                        }, { 
                            text: 'Teste2', 
                            iconCls: 'usuario', 
                            handler: function(){ 
                                var tabs = Ext.getCmp('dynamic-tabs'); 
                                tabs.add({ 
                                    title: 'Teste2', 
                                    closable:true, 
                                    autoLoad: 'iframe.php?url=index.php', 
                                    iconCls: 'usuario' 
                                }).show(); 
                            } 
                        }] 
                    }
                }, { 
                    text: 'Configurações', 
                    iconCls: 'sistema', 
                    handler: function(){ 
                        var tabs = Ext.getCmp('dynamic-tabs'); 
                        tabs.add({ 
                            title: 'Configurações', 
                            closable:true, 
                            autoLoad: 'iframe.php?url=form.php', 
                            iconCls: 'sistema' 
                        }).show(); 
                    }
                }, { 
                    text: 'Relatório Vertical', 
                    iconCls: 'relatorio', 
                    handler: function(){ 
                        var tabs = Ext.getCmp('dynamic-tabs'); 
                        tabs.add({
                            title: 'Relatório Vertical', 
                            closable:true, 
                            autoLoad: 'iframe.php?url=relatorio_v.php', 
                            iconCls: 'relatorio'
                        }).show(); 
                    } 
                }, { 
                    text: 'Relatório Horizontal',
                    iconCls: 'relatorio', 
                    handler: function(){ 
                    var tabs = Ext.getCmp('dynamic-tabs'); 
                    tabs.add({ 
                        title: 'Relatório Horizontal', 
                        closable:true, 
                        autoLoad: 'iframe.php?url=relatorio_h.php', 
                        iconCls: 'relatorio' 
                    }).show(); 
                } 
            },
            '-', { 
                text: 'Sair', 
                iconCls: 'logoff', 
                handler: function(){
                    location.reload() 
                } 
            }] 
        } 
    }, { 
        xtype: 'button', 
        text: 'Abas', 
        iconCls: 'abas', 
        menu: { 
            items: [{ 
                text: 'Criar nova Aba', 
                iconCls: 'tab_add', 
                handler: function(){ 
                    var tabs = Ext.getCmp('dynamic-tabs'); 
                    tabs.add({
                        title: 'Nova Aba', 
                        html: 'Tab Body', 
                        closable:true, 
                        iconCls: 'tab_add' 
                    }).show() 
                } 
            }, { 
                text: 'Ir para a primeira Aba', 
                iconCls: 'tab_go', 
                handler: function(){
                    tabs.setActiveTab(0); 
                }
            }, { 
                text: 'Excluir 2a Aba', 
                iconCls: 'tab_delete', 
                handler: function(){ 
                    var tabs = Ext.getCmp('dynamic-tabs'); 
                    if (tabs.get(1)) { 
                        var tab = tabs.get(1); 
                        tabs.remove(tab); 
                    } 
                } 
            }] 
        } 
    }, { 
        xtype: 'button', 
        text: 'Menus', 
        iconCls: 'usuario', 
        menu: { 
            items: [{ 
                text: 'Sub-menus com título dif.', 
                iconCls: 'usuario', 
                handler: function(){ }, 
                menu: {
                    items: ['Título do Sub-menu', 
                    { 
                        text: 'Sub-menu #1', 
                        iconCls: 'usuario', 
                        handler: function(){ 
                            var tabs = Ext.getCmp('dynamic-tabs');
                            tabs.add({ 
                                title: 'Sub-menu #1', 
                                closable:true, 
                                autoLoad: 'iframe.php?url=phpinfo.php', 
                                iconCls: 'usuario'
                            }).show(); 
                        } 
                    }, { 
                        text: 'Sub-menu #2', 
                        iconCls: 'usuario', 
                        handler: function(){ 
                            var tabs = Ext.getCmp('dynamic-tabs'); 
                            tabs.add({
                                title: 'Sub-menu #2', 
                                closable:true, 
                                autoLoad: 'iframe.php?url=phpinfo.php', 
                                iconCls: 'usuario'
                            }).show(); 
                        } 
                    }] 
                }
            }, { 
                text: 'Sub-menus com título igual',
                iconCls: 'usuario', 
                handler: function(){ }, 
                menu: {
                    items: ['Sub-menus com título igual', 
                    {
                        text: 'Sub-menu #1', 
                        iconCls: 'usuario', 
                        handler: function(){ 
                            var tabs = Ext.getCmp('dynamic-tabs'); 
                            tabs.add({
                                title: 'Sub-menu #1', 
                                closable:true, 
                                autoLoad: 'iframe.php?url=phpinfo.php', 
                                iconCls: 'usuario'
                            }).show(); 
                        }
                    }, { 
                        text: 'Sub-menu #2', 
                        iconCls: 'usuario', 
                        handler: function(){ 
                            var tabs = Ext.getCmp('dynamic-tabs'); 
                            tabs.add({ 
                                title: 'Sub-menu #2', 
                                closable:true, 
                                autoLoad: 'iframe.php?url=phpinfo.php', 
                                iconCls: 'usuario'
                            }).show();
                        } 
                    }] 
                } 
            }, { 
                text: 'Sub-menus sem título', 
                iconCls: 'usuario', 
                handler: function(){ }, 
                menu: { 
                    items: [{ 
                        text: 'Sub-menu #1', 
                        iconCls: 'usuario', 
                        handler: function(){ 
                            var tabs = Ext.getCmp('dynamic-tabs'); 
                            tabs.add({
                                title: 'Sub-menu #1', 
                                closable:true, 
                                autoLoad: 'iframe.php?url=phpinfo.php', 
                                iconCls: 'usuario'
                            }).show(); 
                        } 
                    }, { 
                        text: 'Sub-menu #2', 
                        iconCls: 'usuario', 
                        handler: function(){ 
                            var tabs = Ext.getCmp('dynamic-tabs'); 
                            tabs.add({ 
                                title: 'Sub-menu #2', 
                                closable:true, 
                                autoLoad: 'iframe.php?url=phpinfo.php', 
                                iconCls: 'usuario'
                            }).show(); 
                        } 
                    }] 
                } 
            }, { 
                text: 'Sub-menu grande', 
                iconCls: 'usuario', 
                handler: function(){ }, 
                menu: { 
                    items: [{
                        text: 'Nível #1', 
                        iconCls: 'usuario', 
                        handler: function(){ }, 
                        menu: { 
                            items: [{ 
                                text: 'Nível #2', 
                                iconCls: 'usuario', 
                                handler: function(){ }, 
                                menu: { 
                                    items: [{ 
                                        text: 'Nível #3', 
                                        iconCls: 'usuario', 
                                        handler: function(){ }, 
                                        menu: { 
                                            items: [{ 
                                                text: 'Nível #4 e etc...', 
                                                iconCls: 'usuario', 
                                                handler: function(){ } 
                                            }] 
                                        } 
                                    }] 
                                } 
                            }] 
                        } 
                    }] 
                } 
            }] 
        } 
    }] 
} , { 
    region: 'center', 
    xtype: 'tabpanel', 
    id: 'dynamic-tabs', 
    items: [{
        title: 'Início', 
        autoLoad: 'iframe.php?url=phpinfo.php', 
        iconCls:'home'
}] 
} , { 
    region: 'south', 
    xtype: 'toolbar', 
    id: 'barra', 
    height: 25, 
    items: [{ 
        xtype: 'tbtext', 
        text: 'Pacific Tecnologia da Informação © 2011', 
        html: '<img src=\'imagens/logo_peq.png\' />' 
    }] 
}] 
}); 

var tabs = Ext.getCmp('dynamic-tabs'); tabs.setActiveTab(0); });
```

It's a simple sample menu. I tested in IE version 8 and emulating 7 with compatibility mode.

Interesting observation: In Firefox firebug's console shows:

```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class=" x-viewport">
    <head></head>
    <body id="ext-gen5" class=" ext-gecko ext-gecko3 x-border-layout-ct">
    etc...
```

IE's Developers Tools shows:

```
    <html class=" x-quirks  ext-border-box x-viewport">
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <body class="   ext-ie ext-ie7 x-border-layout-ct" id="ext-gen5" scroll="no">
    Texto - 
    DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
    Texto - Nó de Texto Vazio
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script language="javascript" src="js/ext/adapter/ext/ext-base.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    etc...
```

My HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/ext/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/ext/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/menu.js.php"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/layout.js.php"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/ext/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/ext/resources/css/xtheme-blue.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/layout.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/icones.css.php" /></head>
 
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Guys, I know that error says that IE doesn't understand something, but my problema is why it not work only in IE if it works on other browsers seeing that EXT JS is cross-browser, right ? The error seems to be on this cmd: `F=y.ownerDocument.createRange()` but I'm not sure. Sometimes I want to break each IE developers neck >|

Comment: is the HTML code copy paste? The IE does not close the Header... I will add some HTML code to my post...

Comment: @sra Look my edit, that's my pure entire html. The layout.js.php have no script and menu.js.php is the ext script posted above.

Comment: have you tried the doctype from my post?

Comment: Yes but nothing changes. I'm going mad with this. I think I'll re-write all the code from the begginig.. =S

Comment: Do you know by now whats behind the `el` element? Till know you have just stated out the line and the code within that line...

Comment: @sra `el` is a `DispHTMLDOMTextNode` according by IE Dev Tools. Is an empty text node with some `\n` generated by IE I believe.

Comment: OK, then the next step is to identify at which point the el var get set and from which ExtJS object. You can read back in code and maybe set some breakpoints to archive this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this error previously. In my case I had an entity called `location` and ext created a object from it. Now the IE used the JS native location object and tried to execute methods on it. The error looked much the same as your error.

Use the IE developer toolbar and debug your code to identify the exact object. That's how I solved this issue!

EDIT based on the new Demo code:

Your HTML file should start with

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

I never had any problems with these settings. The debugger may look different, cause ExtJS will add classes at runtime, but this should be your source HTML file.

Comment: What you mean 'entity'? I'll check my code again, but I'm always avoid to use reserved keywords...

Comment: With entity I mean a data object, but never mind that. Use the debug Version of to ext js and Start the IE dev Tools as I mentioned above...

Comment: Well, I don't really know how to use IE dev tools, don't know were to find errors messages in that. But with debug version the error that IE showed to me is this: `Object doesn't support this property or method` on line 520 that contains this instruction: `range = el.ownerDocument.createRange();`. It still other browser render the app okay.

Comment: You will need to identify whats behind `el` and `ownerDocument` to solve this. Further help without a demo is not possible cause it is just guessing. The other thing that is important is the Version of the IE and if you had done an update since you last tested it...

Comment: I reduced my code to just center and south region and works, when I put the north region with the toolbar - even with just one button - IE crashes.. I think that is the `xtype`

Comment: @Márcio OK, so all works fine without the north region as `xtype: 'toolbar'`? 
I wouldn't do it the way you do that. I would pack the toolbar as item of the north region. That should also fix your problem. I didn't seen that before.

Comment: Yes, if I remove the toolbar ext works well. I'll try the way you said.

Comment: I did not found the error. Probably my mistake but I tried everything you guys said here plus tons of web searches. I'll chose your answer because you helped more than anyone and your suggestions pointed to a more clear way. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you try to call a property or method that IE is the only one that can't understand. Are you using some natives objects that could be known by everyone except IE ?

Answer (score 1):

You call a method or a property on an object that doesn't support it.
Try to find what kind of object is that one and add the method to it.

Can you provide some code please?

Answer (score 1):

can you include ext-all-debug.js instead of ext-all.js? And then tell us which line is throwing the error?
Some possible solutions
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?81087-OPEN-418-3.0.0-el.ownerDocument.createRange()-error-in-IE8

[ext js - el.ownerDocument.createRange() errors in IE 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896902/ext-js-el-ownerdocument-createrange-errors-in-ie-8)

Comment: Like I commented on @sra answer: "But with debug version the error that IE showed to me is this: `Object doesn't support this property or method` on line **520** that contains this instruction: `range = el.ownerDocument.createRange();`"

Comment: I see. Is it possible for you to look at the stack trace and find out what "el" is referring to?

Comment: I put a stop point in this line with firebug and putting mouse over `el` it shows: `<TextNode textContent="\n\n\n     ">` . And over `ownerDocument` it shows: `Document /frame/` *frame* is my root directory e.g. `localhost/frame`. It helps ??

Comment: I have updated my answer with some links, I don't know if you have been through them already

Comment: Sencha foruns is unavailable =s And seeing the stack topic I tryied what tha guy said. First of all I had no `html: '&nbsp;'` like he sais in his post, but I got some `html:'Tag body'` that I changed to `html:'<span></span>'` as he changed. But the erros still the same

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I troubleshoot this in Ext/IE:

1. Check for dangling commas. Older versions of IE hate a comma before a } or ]. Ext's coding style makes this mistake likely. I use this (jEdit) regex to search: ",(\s*\n*\s*[}|]])"
2. Use alerts to identify the line of your code that leads to the error. You will probably be passing an object to an Ext function. This object is likely null/undefined or not of the type expected. An alert(typeof somevar) might be helpful here. If there is no obvious entry point, look to your "xtype" definitions and listeners: one of these might be invalid
3. Watch out of global poisoning. I ran into a problem recently where I had a global JS variable with the same name as a DIV's id property. IE tries to make a global variable out of every DOM id,and I was picking up the wrong one. If this is affecting you it is probably because a local function variable is missing the "var" keyword and thus conflicting with he global space.

Comment: I had no time to check out your sugestions, but I'll try soon. Thank you.

Comment: 1. Commas is okay;
2. The `el` object that causes the error refers to a textNode created by IE itself. I doesn't supports `createRange` function.;
3. I got none except EXT script, no variable name can crash with objects ids or other ext vars

Answer (score 0):

You sir have probably encountered the dreaded "owner.createDocument.createRange IE Bug"

Some solutions point to the fact that the first node is not valid.

Here are two possible solutions :

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?7912-CLOSED-owner.createDocument.createRange-JS-error&highlight=createRange

[ext js - el.ownerDocument.createRange() errors in IE 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896902/ext-js-el-ownerdocument-createrange-errors-in-ie-8)

Good luck

Comment: I've already looked into these links, but I'll revise them again. thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's an IE Bug, may it fixed on version 4.